# Push a new folder from local machine to Github

Tags: github, push, github-for-mac

I have been confused about github and local machine for a long time..When I tried to push the existing folder in my local machine to github, I always created an empty repo in github and push the existing folder from the local machine to github. Yet I wonder if there's a way that I can connect my local folder with github and push it directly to github without creating a repo in github first? Thanks!

Comment: Yes...is there any way to do so...?

Comment: Here's the steps on how to push an existing git repository in your local machine to github : https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line